# Vim package development python support for 2, 3, or both?

Tags: vimscript-python, plugin-development

Apparently there are [some issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30443836/install-vim-via-homebrew-with-python-and-python3-support#answer-30516109) preventing `vim` from being built with both `python` and `python3` support under many linux distributions and OSX.  This makes it difficult or impossible for many users to use packages (AKA plugins, addons, etc.) which use python 2 while also using packages that use python 3.

As such, is it recommended to use one of either python 2 or python 3 when developing vim packages?  Or should packages include both python 2 and python 3 code and switch between them using [has("python")](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#has())?

Comment: Related post: [Drawbacks of using Python to develop new code in a VIM plugin](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/14598/778)